# Facing trouble in insertion of data in to table after creating table by using hook_update_N function

Tags: database

I have created a table by using hook_update_N() function. After creation, if i am trying to insert data into table but it is not storing. Is there any thing else is there to do after creating table by using hook_update_N()..?

Comment: Nope, creating it should do the trick. Please describe *how* you insert the data, and any error messages you see.

Comment: trying insert data by using node_save() function.. no error messages..

Comment: Where have you placed the call to `node_save()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using [`drupal_write_record`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7), be aware of this warning in the documentation

> Do not use `drupal_write_record()` within `hook_update_N()` functions, since the database schema cannot be relied upon when a user is running a series of updates. Instead, use `db_insert()` or `db_update()` to save the record.

You should be using `db_insert` or `db_update` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `node_save()` inside the `hook_update_N()` function.  You must first *create* the schema for your new table by running the update script. After having run the update script, use a DB manager such as *phpMyAdmin* to check that it has been created in the database.

Then, to *use* the schema, the `node_save()` function must to be called from your custom module, not from inside `hook_update_N()`.